# How to push image(from url) into aws without saving image into localhost/paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-s3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, amazon-cloudfront

I have a image url like

@img = 'http://www.google.com/images/logos/ps_logo.png'

Is there any process to push this image directly into aws without using paperclip/saving into localhost in ruby on rails.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Let me know if you'd like further information in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is. AWS has a JS library that allows direct upload from the browser. There is a blog post here:

http://blog.littleblimp.com/post/53942611764/direct-uploads-to-s3-with-rails-paperclip-and

And here using JQuery

http://pjambet.github.io/blog/direct-upload-to-s3/

However, a little more googling should find a wealth of advice and gems.

There will be a bit of wrangling involved as the method of authentication is non-trivial.